# Setting a default value when populating dropdown with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've some code I've been working on, which uses AJAX to generate a second dropdown based on information in the database.

For example
If you select BMW
it will populate the second list with all available BMW models, this is working correctly, but I would like one of the fields in the second drop down to remain SELECT, or ANY, so that they can search solely on car Make.

I've had a look online and the solutions seem very complicated for what I would hoped was a simple fix, I'm now stuck on how to fix the issue, should I just add a separate form for just make? Although this wouldn't be as user friendly.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <form id="fitment_search" action="gallery.php" method="GET">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h5>Vehicle Make:</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="make" onchange="get_model(this.value)">
                                <option value="make">SELECT</option>
                                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($makeResult)) : ?>
                                    <option
                                        value="<?php echo $row['make']; ?>"><?php echo $row['make']; ?></option>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </select>
                            <div class="select__arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h5>Model:</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="model" id="fitment_model">
                                <option value="">SELECT</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="select__arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><i
                            class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Search Now
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Heres the code form the seperate php file.

```
    $make=$_GET["make"];  

    $sql2 = "SELECT `model` FROM `fitment` WHERE `make` = '$make' ORDER BY `model` ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);    
    ?>

    <select name="models"> <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row['model']?>"><?php echo $row['model'] ?></option><?php

    } ?>

    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change:

```
<select name="models"> <?php
```

TO

```
<select name="models"> 
  <option value="" >Select</option>    
  <?php
```

Comment: Hey I found the same solution when I looked at the code after submitting the question, cheers mate